# submit the full path for file in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the fuul path for a file using php.
for that I used this :

```
<form method="get" action="">
            <label for="fichier">Choisir votre fichier : </label>
            <input type="file" name="fichier"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="procéder">
        </form>
```

I want when I submit my form to submit the full path for my file not only it's base name.

How can I do that in php ?

Comment: You can't.  You can get the filename and the path to where it is stored temporarily on the server after upload.

Comment: You can't, the browser won't tell you the full path of the file any more for security reasons.

Comment: @AbraCadaver What about using JavaScript ?

Comment: I'm not positive, but I don't think so.  I'm not a js whiz, but as I remember, it has no access to client info either, only the browser does and it doesn't expose that for security reasons.

Answer (score -1):

if you use local host would be

```
http://localhost/path to the file  /
```

if you use a server would be your URL to that file including http:// and / at the end

Comment: I Can Has Cheezburger?